# Required Option with and without arguments in Apache Common CLI

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I need to have the same option with and without argument. Example,

```
CLIParser -d 2 abc.txt
```

In above case `d=2`

```
CLIParser -d abc.txt
```

In above case `d=1`

I tried using  `.optionalArg(true)` and `.numberOfArgs(1)` but nothing seems to work. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me.

```
Option.builder("d").hasArg().optionalArg(true).build();
```

You need both:

```
hasArg = true and optionalArg = true
```

If there is no arg then:

```
CommandLine.getOptionValue("d");
```

will return `null`. You can change that to `1` as your requirement.